# How to find the product of elements in a multiple tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension, product

I have a list below:

```
list = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

How do I return a list containing the products of the elements in the tuples, ie.:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9]
```

where

1*1 = 1 is the 1st element in the new list

1*2 = 2 is the 2nd element in the new list

1*3 = 3 is the 3rd element in the new list

2*1 = 2 is the 4th element in the new list

2*2 = 4 is the 5th element in the new list

etc.

A way to do this in a list comprehension would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried anything? Also, naming a variable `list` is a terrible idea, be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use libraries, a simple list comprehension will do that just fine:

```
lst = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]

products = [a*b for a,b in lst]

# [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

[reduce(mul, t, 1) for t in my_list]
```

Comment: @Leockl my approach will solve your problem no matter how many elements you have in your tuples